# Spring Data ElasticSearch - Mapping _source to java object

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to map _source to java pojo as below but I am getting null in response

```
public class ESDocument {
    
    @Id
    @Field(name = "_id")
    private String id;
    
    @Field(name = "_source", type = FieldType.Nested)
    private Object source;
    
}
```

Response says source filed is empty

```
SearchHit{id='12345_11', score=3.0, sortValues=[], content=ESDocument(id=12345_11, source=null), highlightFields={}}
```

Can someone advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Spring Data Elasticsearch on reading maps `ESDocument` from the content of the Elasticsearch __source_ field and sets the `@Id` from the __id_ field.

Comment: My elastic search has both fields _id and _source. I need _source field so I can modify the entire map based on my requirement

Comment: I know that the search result has __id- and __source_. And this is automatically mapped to en entity. You should explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to update fields in the document and save back in elastic search index.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ObjectMapper` to convert your response to a `POJO/List<POJO>`
Something like this:

```
Search Response response = repository.search(...);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
    POJO pojo = mapper.convertValue(hit.getSourceAsMap(), POJO.class);
    // process pojo here...
}
```